# .travis.yml version setting for postgresql ignored

Tags: travis-ci

With the following in [my `.travis.yml`](https://github.com/orientation/orientation/blob/f9850e86a97eff77298f54ce68ca0a07c173e81a/.travis.yml):

```
addons:
  postgresql: "9.3"
before_script:
  - psql --version
  - psql -c 'SELECT version();' -U postgres
```

I get the following output:

```
$ psql --version
$ psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4.0
$ psql -c 'SELECT version();' -U postgres

PostgreSQL 9.1.14 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit
```

Obviously there's something wrong here but I'm not sure how to tell Travis to actually use the postgres version I specified. I followed [the instructions in Travis Docs](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/using-postgresql/#Selecting-a-PostgreSQL-Version). This seems like a bug.

This is an issue because I'm using the new `json` column type and therefore getting the following error:

```
PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "json" does not exist
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took a look and what you're encountering is essentially a *bug* in how our YAML parsing handles duplicate keys. Fixing how we handle this is something we're working.

You have two `addons:` keys in your `.travis.yml` files

1. https://github.com/orientation/orientation/blob/f9850e86a97eff77298f54ce68ca0a07c173e81a/.travis.yml#L6-L7
2. https://github.com/orientation/orientation/blob/f9850e86a97eff77298f54ce68ca0a07c173e81a/.travis.yml#L39-L41

What happens is that the **last** key wins and your postgres stuff is silently *discarded*.

If you combine them like the following, it will work as desired.

`addons:
  postgres: "9.3"
  code_climate:
     repo_token: 75408d377a0b3c1ab512bf3fb634617bccf2a1065f8c513e352139427ec8e1fb`

See https://github.com/solarce/orientation/commit/8dd4c1c10b8470ff3529af1d6591d619f211354d and https://travis-ci.org/solarce/orientation/jobs/83220170 for an example of this

Please feel free to also reach out to support@travis-ci.com if you have any other questions

Comment: Thanks! That seems obvious now but it's true that mixing `addon` declarations for Slack and crucial dependencies does feel odd.