# Travis CI ignores Postgres version specification

Tags: postgresql, elixir, yaml, travis-ci

I have been banging my head about this for a few hours but could just not find an answer. This is absurd.

My `.travis.yml`:

```
language: elixir
elixir: "1.6.4"
otp_release: "20.1"
addons:
  - postgresql: "9.6"
services:
  - postgresql
env:
  - MIX_ENV=test
before_script:
  - psql --version
  - psql -c 'SELECT version();' -U postgres
  - psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres
  - cp config/travis_test.exs config/test.secret.exs
  - mix do ecto.migrate
```

Upon creating the DB, I always get the following error:

`** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42704 (undefined_object): type "jsonb" does not exist`

Apparently, the two commands show that the Postgres version is always 9.2, the default on `trusty` images.

There was a similar question: [.travis.yml version setting for postgresql ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872000/travis-yml-version-setting-for-postgresql-ignored), but in that case the OP apparently included `addons` key twice in the `.travis.yml` file.

I have no idea what happened in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Eventually, setting the dist explicitly to `xenial` solved it for me.

```
language: elixir
elixir: "1.6.4"
otp_release: "20.1"
dist: xenial
addons:
  - postgresql: "9.6"
services:
  - postgresql
env:
  - MIX_ENV=test
before_script:
  - psql --version
  - psql -c 'SELECT version();' -U postgres
  - psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres
  - cp config/travis_test.exs config/test.secret.exs
  - mix do ecto.migrate
```

However I still have no idea why it didn't work on `trusty`, since `Build system information` output specifically stated that version 9.6.6 is also preinstalled on the system.